# What is the difference between the boolean “usecapture” argument in addEventListener() and the “capture” property of the alternative options object?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

The [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) have such different wording between both variants of the `addEventListener()` call that I wonder if these two actually have the same effect or not!?

```
addEventListener('click', console.log, true);

removeEventListener('click', console.log, {capture: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, they are effectively the same.**

Only the [DOM spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-eventtarget-addeventlistener) itself seems to enlighten on this one. Playing around in the browser console confirms this.

Comment: @Teemu Corrected that one... sorry about the confusion.